# Eicha 2:5 Targum - seemingly out of order

Tags: mourning-aveilus, lamentations-eicha, targumin

[Eicha 2:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39728&st=&pgnum=19) Targum translates תאניה ואניה as אבילותא ואנינותא. Does not Aninus come before Aveilus? How can this targum be explained?

Comment: New losses while still mourning the old ones.

Comment: @Yishai: Sounds like a good explanation. Is there a source that says this?

Comment: not that I know of.

Comment: Are you asking on the Passuk or the Targum? Do you think that the Targum may have mistranslated? If not, the question is on the passuk; not the Targum. || Do you have any reason to think that the popular usage of synonymous terms for mourning by Hazal, ought to correspond to usage in Biblical Hebrew? || Consider clarifying your question.